# How to remove <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> when using "xml" in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xmlcontent = "some text with <tags>"

bs = BeautifulSoup(xmlcontent, "xml")

print bs
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
some text with <tags>
```

Is it possible to not output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I know if using `lxml`, to remove the added `<body>` tags I could do:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(xmlcontent, "lxml")

print bs.body.next
```

Is there an equivalent to use with `xml` so that the xml version and encoding are not included?

I was choosing to use `xml` over `lxml` as the contents being parsed will most always be in xml format - is this the best choice or can I just use `lxml` for xml content?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xmlcontent = "some text with <tags>"

bs = BeautifulSoup(xmlcontent, "xml")

bs = bs.encode_contents()

print type(bs) # it's a string

print bs

# some text with <tags>
```